# Конвертирование массива байтов во float

Tags: java, android

Код:

```
byte[] array = { 50, 0, 0, 0 };
ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.wrap(array);
float i = b.getFloat() * 0.5f;
Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, "result " + i);
```

Правильным ответом должно быть 25, но у меня белиберда - 3.7252903E-9.
Что я делаю не так?

Comment: float - это 4 байта в определенном [формате](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8). Что у вас на самом деле хранится в массиве?

Comment: `{ 50, 0, 0, 0 }` - это даже не близко `50.0f`, ибо float хранится по-другому. Так что это не "белиберда", а правильный ответ для данных байтов.

Comment: `50.0f` - это `{ 66 72 0 0 }` в big-endian (если не путаю endian-ы) и `{ 0 0 72 66 }` в little-endian.

Comment: ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(size).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
        b.put(array, startByte - 1, size);
        b.position(0);

Вот так все заработало. А в итоге получается я говорю что младший байт в начале? Или почему это мне помогло?

Comment: byte[] array = new byte[]{50, 0, 0, 0};
                ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.wrap(array).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
                float i = b.getInt() * 0.5f;
                Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, "result " + i);